# I cant not used compose withRouter and withAlert Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I cant not use compose withRouter and withAlert 
It's work only withRouter but I cant used this.props.alert.success...............................................................................................................................

It show error
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { withAlert } from "react-alert";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import { compose } from "redux";
import { firestore } from "../../firebase/firebase.utils";
class Updatestatusproperty extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: this.props.match.params.id,
      status:1
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.alert.success("อัพเดทสถานะบ้านเสร็จสิ้น");  
    // firestore
    // .collection("house")
    // .doc(this.state.id)
    // .update({status:this.state.status})
    // .then(() => {
    //     this.props.alert.success("อัพเดทสถานะบ้านเสร็จสิ้น");
    // })
    // .catch((err) => {
    //    console.log(err)
    // });
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ status: event.target.value });
    console.log( event.target.value )
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container
        maxWidth="md"
        style={{ paddingTop: "4%", paddingBottom: "4%" }}
      >
        <Paper
          variant="outlined"
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2",
            backgroundPosition: "center",
            backgroundSize: "cover",
            backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
            padding: "4%",
          }}
        >
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Typography variant="h4">{"อัพเดทสถานะ"}</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Typography variant="h6">{"อัพเดทสถานะบ้าน"}</Typography>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={4}>
              <FormControl fullWidth>
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">
                  อัพเดทสถานะบ้าน
                </InputLabel>
                <Select name="sizefamily" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.status}>
                  <MenuItem value={1}>พร้อมขาย</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={2}>อยู่ระหว่างเจรจา</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={3}>ขายออกไปแล้ว</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={3}>
              <Button
                type="submit"
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                fullWidth
                size="large"
                style={{ backgroundColor: "#55aa54", marginTop: "3.5%" }}
                onClick={this.handleSubmit}
              >
                อัพเดทสถานะ
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Paper>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default compose(withRouter(Updatestatusproperty),withAlert());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the compose function incorrectly.

You need to pass the HOCs, withRoute as arguments to it without calling it like below

```
export default compose(withRouter,withAlert())(Updatestatusproperty);
```

Comment: i change it and show error ×
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: I updated my answer, withAlert needs to be invoked since it is returns a function which then takes in the component as argument

Comment: I updated my answer, withAlert needs to be invoked since it is returns a function which then takes in the component as argument